# How to execute python script in nodeJS Back-end

Tags: python, node.js, spawn

I would like to execute a test.py from my nodeJS back-end, after watching several tutorial i writed this code :

```
function runTestPy(req, res) {
  const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
  const process = spawn('python', ['./test.py']);
  process.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(data.toString());
    console.log('out');
  });
  process.stdout.on('end', () => {
    console.log('fin');
  });
  console.log('merce');
}

module.exports.runTestPy = runTestPy;
runTestPy('', '');
```

and here my test.py :

```
print("hello world from python ")
```

The problem is that the function is working if I launch it independently from the command `node test.py`, but when I launch it from the project (after a `npm run dev`) its just do not work, it does not print "hello world from python" and the "out" log.

I think the problem come from

```
  const process = spawn('python', ['./test.py']);
```

but i just dont know how to install python in nodeJS and how to use it.

Comment: You don't "install python in node". Python is installed on the machine. You're just calling an OS executable, could be any script, not just python... Please show your file with the NPM commands

Comment: Although, why do you need node and python? It would be easier to just import and run Python modules from another python application

Comment: I think the issue is that you have written a relative path as `'./test.py'`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Python-shell**

```
npm install python-shell
```

Import the package :

```
import {PythonShell} from 'python-shell';

PythonShell.run('test.py', null, function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('finished');
});
```

Comment: How to pass multiple arguments in this library so we can read it in python script as an argument.